# How to modify MySQL export to CSV?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, redirect, modx

I have MySQL table and I have to export two columns. I do that query now:

```
SELECT id,uri
FROM modx-sitecontent
INTO OUTFILE 'uris.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But id in database it's an ordinary number, but in CSV I need something like this:

```
[[~id]]
```

For example in database **5** in CSV **[[~5]]**

Help me please

Comment: Use PHP to write to a file with the CSV format and save as a `.csv` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **Google spreadsheets** to modify **CSV** file and it's solved my problem